# Ideal gas equation for adiabatic process

Tags: thermodynamics, thermal-conductivity

In an adiabatic expansion or compression of gases, does the ideal gas equation change from $PV=nRT$ to $PV^{\gamma} = nRT$? If so, then why as pressure and volume are inversely related in both the cases and the only difference is in their heat exchange process with the surroundings? Why is only $\gamma = C_{p}/C_{v}$  used in the equation as neither volume nor pressure is constant here?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

> In an adiabatic expansion or compression of gases, does the ideal gas equation change from = to $$^=$$

No. See the equation PV = nRT is valid for an ideal gas for any process.

In Adiabatic process,
$$PV^ = k ≠ nRT$$where k is a constant.

However Ideal gas equation equally holds true.
$$PV = nRT$$
here P,V and T are variable.

> Why is only =/ used in the equation as neither volume nor pressure is constant here?

See in the cases of ideal gases, Cp and Cv are treated as constants.Even though P and V are not constant, heat capacity at constant Pressure and constant Volume - Cp and Cv are constants for ideal gas.And their ratio is called Adiabatic Index or Gamma.

---

P.S. If you still have any doubt,comment below.

Comment: In adiabatic process P.V is not constant as temperature is not the same but PV/T =nR =constant  PV^gamma =k. Is V/T is same as V^gamma

Comment: @user270071 Just because two quantities are constant, it doesn't mean that they are the same! The two quantities that you're comparing don't even have the same dimension...

Comment: @user270071 I agree with Philip on this one.